# NullPointerException only for the firs time when accessing FirebaseDatabase reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase realtime database and I'm facing one issue with it. Only for the very first time of accessing the FireBase db (When no db references have been created and you get a reference for the first time) I'm getting the below null pointer exception. here's my code which causes the error

```
@NonNull
private DatabaseReference getRootReference() {
    String rootRef = getRootDbRef();
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    return database.getReference(rootRef);
}
```

Throwing the error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzae.zza(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference
    at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzab.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:276)
    at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzab.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:90)
    at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzad.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:101)
    at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzad.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:42)
    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:357)
    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReference(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:201)
```

But for the next execution (Or if I debug and evaluate), I don't get this error and it will successfully return the reference. I'm calling this method from a `Service` from the `onStartCommand` method.

Comment: it might help https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1447

Comment: @sourabhkaushik Thanks! That link helped.. I upgraded the library version and that fixed the issue!